# Read slave, read-write master setup

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask, SQLAlchemy webapp which uses a single mysql server. I want to expand the database setup to have a read-only slave server such that I can spread the reads between both master and slave while continuing to write to the master db server.

I have looked at few options and I believe I can't do this with plain SQLAlchemy. Instead I'm planning to create 2 database handles in my webapp, one each for master and slave db servers. Then using a simple random value use either the master/slave db handle for "SELECT" operations.

However, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go with using SQLAlchemy. Any suggestion/tips on how to pull this off?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have an example of how to do this on my blog at http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/ .  Basically you can enhance the Session so that it chooses from master or slave on a query-by-query basis.   One potential glitch with that approach is that if you have one transaction that calls six queries, you might end up using both slaves in one request....but there we're just trying to imitate Django's feature :)

A slightly less magic approach that also establishes the scope of usage more explicitly I've used is a decorator on view callables (whatever they're called in Flask), like this:

```
@with_slave
def my_view(...):
   # ...
```

with_slave would do something like this, assuming you have a Session and some engines set up:

```
master = create_engine("some DB")
slave = create_engine("some other DB")
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=master))

def with_slave(fn):
    def go(*arg, **kw):
        s = Session(bind=slave)
        return fn(*arg, **kw)
    return go
```

The idea is that calling `Session(bind=slave)` invokes the registry to get at the actual Session object for the current thread, creating it if it doesn't exist - however since we're passing an argument, scoped_session will assert that the Session we're making here is definitely brand new.

You point it at the "slave" for all subsequent SQL.   Then, when the request is over, you'd ensure that your Flask app is calling `Session.remove()` to clear out the registry for that thread.  When the registry is next used on the same thread, it will be a new Session bound back to the "master".

Or a variant, you want to use the "slave" just for that call, this is "safer" in that it restores any existing bind back to the Session:

```
def with_slave(fn):
    def go(*arg, **kw):
        s = Session()
        oldbind = s.bind
        s.bind = slave
        try:
            return fn(*arg, **kw)
        finally:
            s.bind = oldbind
    return go
```

For each of these decorators you can reverse things, have the Session be bound to a "slave" where the decorator puts it on "master" for write operations.    If you wanted a random slave in that case, if Flask had some kind of "request begin" event you could set it up at that point.

Comment: Thnx zzzeek this helps a lot. Kudos to all the awesome work on sqlalchemy.

Comment: Rad comment, great code examples too! It would be nice if sqlalchemy had some way to do query analysis and route automatically, but in a world where a query may cause a tmp table or other write operation as a result of what would presumably normally be read only that would requires something like requesting the query plan from the backend prior to submitting the query and would be more hassle than it would be worth for most cases.

Comment: we have the "query analysis" option, though it requires you write the analysis yourself.  The horizontal sharding system illustrates an example of this kind of technique, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/horizontal_shard.html.

Comment: Hooks to have a callback function for deciding how to shard queries is fine and all, but really something like proper query inspection classification for separating read ops from write ops is something probably beyond the scope for the majority of sqlalchemy users. Really I would hope that at some point in the near future there are some basic implementations of these strategies available as boilerplate in SA.

Comment: I wouldn't consider distinguishing between "read" and "write" to be "query analysis", i was referring to analyzing a SELECT statement to determine which shards are necessary in a multiple-shard setup.   Distinguishing between "read" and "write" in SQLAlchemy is a no-brainer since all write operations occur within flush().   But the truth is, this still cant be routed "automatically", as a combination of multiple flushes/selects would need to all be on the writer, and SQLAlchemy can't read the future

Comment: Analysing the queries to choose a session would be a bad idea in some cases. You want your reads to be done in the same transaction as your writes in case your reads are impacted by what your writes did.
Imagine that in the same call, you delete a row of a table and then you return the sum of a column of all the records of this table. If you use two different transactions, the sum would contain the row you just deleted because the other transaction is not committed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Or, we can try another way. Such as we can declare two different class with all the instance attributes the same but the `__bind__` class attribute is different. Thus we can use **rw** class to do read/write and **r** class to do read only. :)

I think this way is more easy and reliable. :)

We declare two db models because we can have tables in two different db with the same names. This way we can also bypass the 'extend_existing' error when two models with the same **__tablename__**.

Here is an example:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'rw': 'rw', 'r': 'r'}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model_RW = db.make_declarative_base()

class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'common'
    __bind_key__ = 'r'

class A(db.Model_RW):
    __tablename__ = 'common'
    __bind_key__ = 'rw'
```

Comment: can you improve your answer by providing a example of creation, defining and usage of two databases with different read and write accessebility

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is too late! I use a `slave_session` to query the slave DB

```
class RoutingSession(SignallingSession):
def __init__(self, db, bind_name=None, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, **options):
    self.app = db.get_app()
    if bind_name:
        bind = options.pop('bind', None)
    else:
        bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine

    self._bind_name = bind_name
    SessionBase.__init__(
        self, autocommit=autocommit, autoflush=autoflush,
        bind=bind, binds=None, **options
    )

def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
    if self._bind_name is not None:
        state = get_state(self.app)
        return state.db.get_engine(self.app, bind=self._bind_name)
    else:
        if mapper is not None:
            try:
                persist_selectable = mapper.persist_selectable
            except AttributeError:
                persist_selectable = mapper.mapped_table

            info = getattr(persist_selectable, 'info', {})
            bind_key = info.get('bind_key')
            if bind_key is not None:
                state = get_state(self.app)
                return state.db.get_engine(self.app, bind=bind_key)
        return SessionBase.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)


class RouteSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SQLAlchemy.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.slave_session = self.create_scoped_session({'bind_name': 
'slave'})

    def create_session(self, options):
        return orm.sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession,db=self,**options)

db = RouteSQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata, query_class=orm.Query)
```