# Heroku horizontal scaling

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a python app running on Heroku using a PostgreSQL database.  If I create a database follower, will that follower be used to balance the read database load automatically?  I know this provides me a failover copy of sorts, but will it relieve my database load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- you'll need to configure your Python software to send SQL queries to both the follower AND the master database in order to actually 'relieve' your database load.

If you're using Django, you'll want to read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

If you're using SQLAlchemy, you'll want to read this: [read slave , read-write master setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947918/read-slave-read-write-master-setup)