# How do I work with a PostgreSQL replication setup with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, replication, database-replication

Is there any way to configure SQLAlchemy to work with a Postgres replication setup where I want all writes to go to a master, and reads to go through a single slave?

Comment: Set up one session for master and one for the slave and update the code accordingly? I don't think there's a way to automatically make that distinction at the sqlalchemy level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read slave , read-write master setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947918/read-slave-read-write-master-setup)